# Extending a .NET 7 Winforms application to act as a Grpc-Server

Tags: c#, grpc, http2, grpc-c#

I need to extend a .NET 7 (C#) based Winforms app to also act as a Grpc server. The Grpc server does not need to interact with the GUI elements; this effort servers as a migration path from a fat-client to a server/client architecture.

So, added the necessary Grpc packages and created a proto file for a login request to get started. All that has been added to start the http-Server to handle Grpc-requests is aligned with [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and looks like this:

```
public class GrpcServerApp
{
    private LoginService loginRPC;
    private WebApplication GrpcServer;

    public GrpcServerApp(GUI.Control control)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new string[] { });
        builder.Services.AddGrpc();
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate()
            .AddCertificateCache();

        GrpcServer = builder.Build();
        GrpcServer.UseAuthentication();
        GrpcServer.MapGrpcService<LoginService>();
        GrpcServer.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client");

        loginRPC = new LoginService(control);

        GrpcServer.StartAsync();
    }
```

(GUI.control just offers the version string of the application) All fine, the project builds and when I start, the newly added web server listens on port 5000 and answers the http request for "/".

But when I try to connect with my simple Grpc client

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address);

var client = new RPC.Login.LoginClient(channel);
RPC.LoginResponse? response = null;
try
{
    response = await client.ClientLoginAsync(
        new RPC.LoginRequest
        {
            Name = UsernameTextBox.Text,
        });
}
```

I get the error response

> HttpProtocolException: The HTTP/2 server closed the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED' (0xd)'

I understand that the client seems to communicate via HTTP 1.1, while the server expects HTTP 2 (or is it vice versa`?). I suspect HTTP/2 is only supported w/ TLS in place - however, I can not figure out how to get there.

The server also only opens and listens on port 5000 (http) and does not open another port for https as I've seen it with an example Grpc app that I've built based on the VisualStudio 2022 Grpc project template. Within this template, there's even less code than I pasted above, so there must be some "magic" going on behind the scenes stemming from the project itself.

So, the basic question is: what is missing to let the client and server establish a proper http/2 connection for Grpc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path your going down by combining a Winforms client application with GRPC server tech, can lead to a whole range of problems.
Suggest that you implement your solution with the steps explained here: [Create a gRPC client and server in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

On the problem that you encountered: GRPC can be used over a unsecure HTTP2 connection by specifying the protocol in the appsettings.

The documentation by Microsoft explains that Protocol Negotiation is used on certain ports.

> TLS is used for more than securing communication. The TLS Application-Layer
> Protocol Negotiation (ALPN) handshake is used to negotiate the
> connection protocol between the client and the server when an endpoint
> supports multiple protocols. This negotiation determines whether the
> connection uses HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2.
>
> If an HTTP/2 endpoint is configured without TLS, the endpoint's
> ListenOptions.Protocols must be set to HttpProtocols.Http2. An
> endpoint with multiple protocols, such as HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2
> for example, can't be used without TLS because there's no negotiation.
> All connections to the unsecured endpoint default to HTTP/1.1, and
> gRPC calls fail.

Going down the rabbit hole on the ListenOptions.Protocols. The configuration of the app you'll build needs to have this configuration:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  }
}
```

Regarding the protocols, more info to be found here: [ListenOptions.Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#listenoptionsprotocols)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I also discovered by using a tiny bare-bones server .NET project that HTTP/s w/o TLS is viable.  


What additionally confused me is that Kestrel seems to be deprecated (judging from NuGet package status), but it still seems to be default in new projects. Which is not immediately clear when starting the first Webserver project in .NET.


So, I decided to dump Winforms from the migration path right at the beginning, as you suggested, and move the "backend" code into a proper Webserver project - as you suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help! If this is the answer to your question, could you mark it as solved?

Comment: I didn't verify your suggestion in my specific setup, but your response certainly gives clarity that allows to mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GRPC (.net framework ) in my project as a "windows service" for the server and I can choose wich port to expose , it's the same as winform, I'm using the following codes :

- For server part :

  ```
    int Port = 30051;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server
        {
            Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterImpl()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
        };
        server.Start();
  ```

}

-For client part :

```
        Channel channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:30051",ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
        String user = "you";

        var reply = client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = user });
        Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
```

It's from this exemple : https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.46.x/examples/csharp/Helloworld/GreeterClient/Program.cs

it's not using the last grpcCore implementation, but I guess you can do the same.