# Establishing a gRPC connection in .NET w/o encryption

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, http2, kestrel-http-server

## Summary

I know this problem has been discussed previously, for different .NET (Core) releases and framework setups. I've read the answers and documentation and implemented accordingly (see references and implementation below), but still fail to create a gRPC HTTP/2 connection **across different machines**.

This means: gRPC without encryption **works fine if**

- the server binds to localhost or a local interface address
- the client runs on the same machine and connects to that address

But the **connection** **fails with the depicted exception when the client runs on another machine.**  It tries to connect via the same network interface over which a local connect works . Exception message is:

```
Error starting gRPC Call. HttpRequestException: Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.
```

## References

[My initial question to get to a working client/server setup on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77216508/extending-a-net-7-winforms-application-to-act-as-a-grpc-server): provided input to use gRPC from within a Winforms app and establish unencrypted connection. It basically the approach I'm using now with the described problem.

[Kestrel web server in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#http2-support) Documentation that states HTTP/2 is only possible with TLS - but this is stated because TLS includes protocol negotiation. If both server and client "pre-agree" on HTTP/2 (which is the case in my setup), TLS should not be necessary as stated elsewhere.

[Answer on how to establish unencrypted HTTP/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521993/net-core-3-1-grpc-client-with-unencrypted-http2-connection) This is what I think I'm doing - but as described, it only works within a single host.

## Implementation Details

### Runtime

I'm using C# with .NET 7 with Microsoft.NETCore.App Microsof.AspNetCore.App, plus GrpcAspNetCore 2.57.0.

### Server Code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseNLog();
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICredentialManager, CredentialManager>();
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
   // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
   options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, ServerPort, listenOptions => listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2);
});
var app = builder.Build();

Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<LoginService>();
... other services ...
app.MapGrpcService<TestingService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client.");

app.Run();
```

### Client Code

```
options = new GrpcChannelOptions();
options.LoggerFactory = new NLog.Extensions.Logging.NLogLoggerFactory();
options.Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure;
options.HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
{
   // Potentially set options here. No option for http versions available, though.
};
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

// Only setting HttpHandler is supported by gRPC - setting default HttpClient causes exception; setting both, too.
// options.HttpClient = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(address), DefaultRequestVersion = new Version(2, 0) };

Channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address, options);

var client = new Protos.Login.LoginClient(Channel);
```

### Infomation from Logs

In the client log, there mention of the proxy setup in place which could cause "unexpected results":

```
2023-12-05 13:32:13.1584|INFO|Grpc.Net.Client.GrpcChannel|Proxy configuration is detected. How the gRPC client creates connections can cause unexpected behavior when a proxy is configured. To ensure the client correctly uses a proxy, configure GrpcChannelOptions.HttpHandler to use HttpClientHandler. Note that HttpClientHandler isn't compatible with load balancing.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.1915|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall|Starting gRPC call. Method type: 'Unary', URI: 'http://172.15.15.30:5000/Login.Login/ClientLogin'.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2091|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Subchannel|Subchannel id '1-1' created with addresses: 172.15.15.30:5000
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2091|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager|Channel picker updated.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2159|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Subchannel|Subchannel id '1-1' state changed to Connecting. Detail: 'Connection requested.'.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2159|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager|Channel state updated to Connecting.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2159|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager|Picked queued.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2404|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.SocketConnectivitySubchannelTransport|Subchannel id '1-1' connected to socket 172.15.15.30:5000.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2404|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Subchannel|Subchannel id '1-1' state changed to Ready. Detail: 'Successfully connected to socket.'.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2404|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager|Channel state updated to Ready.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2404|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager|Channel picker updated.
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2404|DEBUG|Grpc.Net.Client.Balancer.Internal.ConnectionManager|Successfully picked subchannel id '1-1' with address 172.15.15.30:5000. Transport status: InitialSocket
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2631|WARN|OptionHunter.Program|first-chance thread exception (Requesting HTTP version 2.0 with version policy RequestVersionOrHigher while unable to establish HTTP/2 connection.)
2023-12-05 13:32:13.2631|WARN|OptionHunter.Program|   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ThrowGetVersionException(HttpRequestMessage request, Int32 desiredVersion, Exception inner)
```

Maybe this leads to this strange behavior. Of course, the proxy is configured for a reason, but only for external connections. Not needed for the gRPC connections.

I will follow the recommendation, but this may have side-effects. Is there a way to tell gRPC "ignore any proxy settings, just connect directly!"?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? (Ah, `HttpConnectionPool.ThrowGetVersionException` was added in .NET 8)

Comment: BTW, [see how it throws in](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c08faf9216976a14f06a11373fbd3aec7671bf7a/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs#L1022) `SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync` - I'm not so sure what you're wanting to do is even possible...

Comment: It is possible, as I just validated a minute ago. Deactivating the proxy on the client side leads to the expected behavior: gRPC requests via an unencrypted http/2 connection between machines. 

Just need to figure out now how to get it working with enabled proxy, as that is needed for outbound communication of other servcies (OneDrive etc.). Setting HttpClient could have side-effects.

Comment: This is .NET 7, btw., as stated in my description.

Comment: Yes, but you're using .NET 8 on the client.

Answer (score 0):

To close this topic: the code I presented originally is indeed the right one to establish unencrypted http/2 connections for gRPC.

Just take care that your Windows setup does not have a proxy configured which does not support http/2..NET will consider and use this proxy, and it's not clear how to avoid this explicitly. This is a different question, though.